# dojox form uploader button is clickable only on the border, but not on the full button

Tags: dojo

I am using IE8

I have created dojo button as below

It has displayed button "Select Files".

### Problem

When I click on top border of button its working fine. When I click on any other places on button file picker dialogbox is not displaying.

When I right click on button and select zoom in option once, I am able to click on all the coordinates of button(after selecting zoom option, it works similar to html button).

Note: I have used flash for multiple file selection.

Please tell how to make this button work by clicking in any place.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if there is other element's borders in front of the button? Try to check with the developer tools option activated on your browser and select "inspect element" (or similar). If another element is detected when you hover over the button, you have your answer.

Apart from that I have no more ideas.